# (Cardinality of the set of) Homotopy classes of continuous maps

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and let $[X,Y]$ be the set of homotopy classes of continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$. Is there some useful description of this set of homotopy classes based on homology, cohomology, homotopy, cohomotopy groups of $X$ and $Y$?

I assume it heavily depends on the type of spaces $X$ and $Y$ one considers. Say I am mostly interested when $Y$ is some compact Lie group ($U(n)$) and $X$ is in principle any compact metric space (if something better can be said for a particular class of compact spaces $X$, I am of course interested).
I should also say that by `description', I mean mostly the cardinality (finite, infinite), but whatever can be said is potentially interesting for me.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127657/homotopy-classes-of-maps-to-lie-groups

Comment: You'll get better results if you restrict $X$ to lie within the class of finite CW complexes and content yourself with pointed homotopy classes. You should look up the work of M. Arkowitz who studied the problem of estimating the cardinality of the group $[\text{finite complex},\text{H-complex}]$ using algebraic invariants. You'll find a brief introduction to his work in ch. 8 of his book *Introduction to Homotopy Theory*.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the problem is trivial after rationalisation. Every Lie group is rationally equivalent (as H-spaces) to a product of odd-degree rational Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces. For example $U_n\simeq_\mathbb{Q}\prod_{k=1,\dots,n}K(\mathbb{Q},2k-1)$, so if $X$ is a finite complex, then $[X,U_n]_\mathbb{Q}\cong[X_\mathbb{Q},(U_n)_\mathbb{Q}]\cong\oplus^n_{k=1} H^{2k-1}(X;\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks for the reference! Proposition 8.2.4 there is indeed very helpful, I can use it to decide when $[X,SU(n)]$ is finite for some CW-complexes $X$ of dimension low enough just based on their Betti numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In some sense, the best approximation to $[X, Y]$ for general spaces $X$ and $Y$ by some (co)homological invariant $h$ is given by something like the (unstable) Adams spectral sequence.  Even though the differentials in such a spectral sequence can be hard to compute, the $E_2$ page of the spectral sequence is just homological algebra involving $h(X)$ and $h(Y)$ (which is not to say it can't still be complicated, but at least it can often be done algorithmically in a range).  Moreover, from how the spectral sequence is set up, the things on the $E_2$-page will provide an upper bound for the cardinality of $[X, Y]$.

A perhaps less technical alternative would be to use the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence for $[-, Y]$, i.e., obstruction theory.  The idea is to build up a map $X \to Y$ by inducting along the skeleta of $X$ or equivalently by resolving $Y$ in terms of its Postnikov tower.  If I recall correctly, the group of lifts at each stage is parametrized by something like $H^n(X; \pi_n Y)$; again these groups would give an upper bound for $[X, Y]$.

These are some pretty powerful, general methods.  But note that often there are easier solutions in particular cases of interest.

Comment: You can of course take $X=S^n$ and $Y=S^3\cong SU_2$ to see just how unfeasible this is in practice for obtaining precise information. It's worth pointing out that neither of these methods takes advantage of the most powerful piece of structure on $[X,Y]$ (namely the algebraic structure).

Comment: @Tyrone Yeah, I completely agree.  I just wanted to provide a perspective on the question raised in the first paragraph, without assuming any kind of structure at all on the spaces $X$ and $Y$.  Though I guess in your example $[X, Y] = \pi_n Y$ is "given", so you could just "describe" $[X, Y]$ by itself :p.

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek aside, maybe it's also worth pointing out the cases when these methods do work well: e.g., Adams SS works nicely if $h(X)$ or $h(Y)$ is free/cofree or is otherwise homologically simple, and obstruction theory works best when $X$ is a finite CW-complex and $Y$ has vanishing homotopy groups above some dimension.

Comment: Oh, and when $X$ only has cells in dimensions where $\pi_* Y = 0$, e.g., $X = \mathbb{C}P^\infty$ and $Y = U$.

Comment: This is a naive question, but: Is it possible that for some spaces $X$, $[X,G]$, where $G$ is a group (say compact Lie group), is non-abelian as a group?

Comment: @user446046 for instance, $[S^3\times S^3,S^3]$ is nonabelian (consider the commutator of the two projections).